# Subdividing NumPy array into Regular Grid

Tags: python, numpy

import numpy as np

I have a rectangle with the following coordinates:

```
ulx,uly = (110, 60) ##uppper left lon, upper left lat
urx,ury = (120, 60) ##uppper right lon, upper right lat
lrx, lry = (120, 50) ##lower right lon, lower right lat
llx, lly = (110, 50) ##lower left lon, lower left lat
```

I want  to divide that single rectangle into 100 regular grids inside that, and
want  to calculate the (ulx, uly), (urx,ury), (lrx, lry), and (llx, lly) for each grid separately:

```
lats = np.linspace(60, 50, 10)
lons = np.linspace(110, 120, 10)

lats = np.repeat(lats,10).reshape(10,10)
lons = np.tile(lons,10).reshape(10,10)
```

I could not imagine what to do then?

Is somebody familiar with such kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use `np.meshgrid`:

```
import numpy as np

lats = np.linspace(50, 60, 11)
lons = np.linspace(110, 120, 11)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(lats, lons)
```

At this point `xx` and `yy` are 2x2 matrices with the corner coordinates of the grid tiles.
If you just want to have a list of coordinates you can use reshape:

```
ulx = np.reshape(xx[1:,:-1],(-1,1))
llx = np.reshape(xx[:-1,:-1],(-1,1))

urx = np.reshape(xx[1:,1:],(-1,1))
lrx = np.reshape(xx[:-1,1:],(-1,1))

uly = np.reshape(yy[1:,:-1],(-1,1))
lly = np.reshape(yy[:-1,:-1],(-1,1))

ury = np.reshape(yy[1:,1:],(-1,1))
lry = np.reshape(yy[:-1,1:],(-1,1))
```

But I would suggest to just use `xx` and `yy`.